# How to override styling in :host?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, shadow-dom

For a specific media query I want to override the styling of ion-content. I am doing it with an ID to have a high specifity:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #content {
        width: 50rem;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the following screenshot (highlighted in yellow) the previous styling of **margin** in :host is not getting overridden. As soon I delete !important of it, my css rules are getting applied.

[image]

How can I completely override :host styling?

Comment: You can't that is the main reason why shadow dom is so underused. Use a wrapper element and set margin to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not,

`:host{ background:green!important }` trumps *inheritable* styles **and** *inline* styles

[image]

```html
<style>
  custom-element {
    font: 18px Arial;display:block;color: white;
    background: purple;
  }
  custom-element.inheritable_important {
    background: blue !important;
  }
  custom-element:before {content:" purple ";}
  custom-element.inheritable_important:before {content:" blue!important  ";}
</style>
<custom-element important=""></custom-element>
<custom-element important="!important"></custom-element>
<custom-element important="" style="background:red"></custom-element>
<custom-element important="!important" style="background:red"></custom-element>
<br>
<custom-element class="inheritable_important" important=""></custom-element>
<custom-element class="inheritable_important" important="!important"></custom-element>
<custom-element class="inheritable_important" important="" style="background:red"></custom-element>
<custom-element class="inheritable_important" important="!important" style="background:red"></custom-element>

<script>
  customElements.define("custom-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.attachShadow({mode:'open'}).innerHTML = `<style>
      :host{background:green${this.getAttribute("important")}}
      </style>style="${this.getAttribute("style")||""}"  host:green${this.getAttribute("important")} `;
    }
  })
</script>
```